# Is there a better way to reference an outer scope to this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope

I've seen and written many javascript methods like this lately:

```
var myObj = {
  dialogOptions: {...},
  init: function() {
    var $this = this;
    var something = $("<div/>").load("...", null, function() {
      $(this).dialog($this.dialogOptions);
    });
  }
}
```

Now, this works due to the nature of closures, but the named variable reference to the  particular level of scope seems awkward. My question is:

Is there some javascript operator that performs `var $this = this;` on the inner scope? Or, perhaps is there a way to traverse the object hierarchy to get the property I'm looking for in the inner scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: nope.

Long answer: the "problem" is the unique nature of `this` in a language where everything is an object. You can't pick and choose about when this means *this* this or means the *other* this.

That's javascript for you. You can do a great deal but it ain't always pretty.

Comment: Would just like to point out that function methods call and apply can re-bind this to other objects.

Comment: that's true, but doesn't apply to the closure case here

Answer (score 1):

There is no definite way to avoid this. However, some libraries provide a way to bind functions to specific scopes - usually allowing syntax like this:

```
(function() { /* do something */ }).bind(whatever)
```

Depending on your taste this may be cleaner than declaring the scope in a separate variable. What the bind in the above context does, is essentially this:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
    var thisFunction = this;
    return function() {
        thisFunction.call(scope);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if `myObj` is a global (or globally reachable) variable, I often do the following:

```
var myObj = {
  dialogOptions: {...},
  init: function() {
    var something = $("<div/>").load("...", null, function() {
      $(this).dialog(myObj.dialogOptions);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Easy to run into problems if you decide to rename the variable tho. Otherwise a decent approach I think

Comment: *faceplam* duh...forgot about that part. Thanks!

Comment: @Jani, for many projects, I find that a search/replace is preferable to a bunch of "var that = this" statements.